# Sheetnode Multisite Javascript error message: 'Unknow line type '' '

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm using sheetnode in a multisite configuration and I'm trying to refer data from an other sheetnode into the current sheetnode.

My issue is very similar to this one https://www.drupal.org/node/1386114 except that clean url are working correctly:

Formula: '=mapping!A1'
Javascript error message: 'Unknow line type '' '

I've been looking at the network tab in chrome and I realize that the difference between a working version and my multisite are few white line at the top of the load/sheetnode call.

I believe that this is part of my problem but I don't know how to resolve it.

Any idea of what's going on ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

It seems obvious now but... if you have the same problem with any other module, just look at the source code.

If you see a lot of white space at the beginning, it's a clue.

Someone might have inadvertently left a closing php tag ('?>') somewhere in his code.

Someone doing copy/paste from online example/sources....

Anyway..I pulled my hair but learned some knowledge. No hard feeling to my colleagues ! ;)